# SQL syntax error in adding a constraint in ALTER TABLE for mysql

Tags: mysql

I have another SQL error that says

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_org1_id` FOREIGN KEY (`org_ID`) REFERENCES `organization` (`o' at line 1

I don't know why I have this error when in fact, I followed correctly the proper syntax for adding a constraint in ALTER TABLE. Can someone help me?

Here is my sql code:

```
ALTER TABLE `administration`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_stud3_id` FOREIGN KEY (`stud_ID`) REFERENCES   `student` (`stud_ID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_faculty3_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`faculty_ID`) REFERENCES `faculty` (`faculty_ID`);
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_org1_id` FOREIGN KEY (`org_ID`) REFERENCES `organization` (`org_ID`)

ALTER TABLE `student_list`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_stud4_id` FOREIGN KEY (`stud_ID`) REFERENCES `student` (`stud_ID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_admin2_id` FOREIGN KEY (`admin_ID`) REFERENCES `administration` (`admin_ID`);
```

Comment: semicolon should be comma

Answer (score 0):

You have terminated your query on wrong place.

Your query is:

```
ALTER TABLE `administration`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_stud3_id` FOREIGN KEY (`stud_ID`) REFERENCES   `student` (`stud_ID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_faculty3_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`faculty_ID`) REFERENCES `faculty` (`faculty_ID`);
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_org1_id` FOREIGN KEY (`org_ID`) REFERENCES `organization` (`org_ID`)
```

should be-

```
ALTER TABLE `administration`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_stud3_id` FOREIGN KEY (`stud_ID`) REFERENCES   `student` (`stud_ID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_faculty3_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`faculty_ID`) REFERENCES `faculty` (`faculty_ID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_org1_id` FOREIGN KEY (`org_ID`) REFERENCES `organization` (`org_ID`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Small mistake, remove `;` semicolon

```
ALTER TABLE `administration` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_stud3_id` FOREIGN KEY (`stud_ID`) REFERENCES   `student` (`stud_ID`),
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_faculty3_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`faculty_ID`)
    REFERENCES `faculty` (`faculty_ID`);// here change semicolon to comma.
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_org1_id` FOREIGN KEY (`org_ID`) 
    REFERENCES `organization` (`org_ID`); // add semicolon here.
```